# C# dll import function to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

This is from C#

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

How to do this in VB.Net ? Can someone please help me thanks!

**Edit**

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Shared Function SendMessage(hwnd As IntPtr, wMsg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```

I want to know if this is correct? if not, what am I missing?

Comment: What do you not understand about the examples of using `DllImport` that you found when you searched the web?

Comment: Please check. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65aa86c4-e017-4c7d-93e5-cd43ca20970e/external-dll-calling-vb-function?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Everything, this is my first time using **DllImport**, if someone can explain on how to use **DllImport** that is much better.

Comment: It's not our responsibility to explain how something works. It's your responsibility to learn that, put it to use and then, if what you think should work doesn't, post what you did and what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the code signatures from [Pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html).

However, you should always try to avoid Win32 native calls and, whenever possible, use a .NET alternative.